# MongoDB DBRefs to query reference collection field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two different collection in two different MongoDB databases.

1. Collection `users` in `db1`:

   ```
   {
     "_id" : "xyz",
     "name" : "John",
     "project_id" : "abc"
   }
   ```
2. Collection `project` in `db2`:

   ```
   {
     "_id" : "abc",
     "regionCode" : "1AB"
   }
   ```

Now I want to get list of all users who belong to region `1AB`. How do I achieve that.
I read about DBRefs. So I changed structure of collections `users` but still i can not query directly to reference collection attribute directly

collection `users` new structure :

```
{
    "_id" : "xyz",
    "name" : "John",
    "project_id" : "abc",
    "projectData" : { 
        "$ref" : "project",
        "$id" : "abc",
        "$db" : "db2"
         }  
    }
```

Now how do I get list of all users that belong to project regioncode `1AB`.

I am using nodejs native client

Comment: You don't need DBRefs, you need [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html)

Comment: lookup in different DB? can you please provide a sample query based upon sample collection I shared in question

Comment: Sorry, I missed the first line. No lookup won't work with different databases. I doubt anything will. It's too complex. DBRef is just a legacy data structure. All magic has gone from it many major versions ago.